# How can I treat an imported value like an array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to generate a google form that has a few hundred options in a drop down.

I have all the name values in a single cell formatted as follows:

'user1','user2','user3'

It is set as in the code as follows:

```
var studentNames = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REDACTED').getSheetByName('Student List').getRange(3,3).getValues();
```

When I use this variable as shown below it treats it all as a singe value instead of an array.

```
.setChoiceValues([studentNames])
```

Any help in where to go from here?

Comment: Have you tried `split(',')`?

Comment: How about `studentNames.split(",")`

Comment: I get TypeError: Cannot find function split in object ['user1','user2'....

I think maybe the split function doesn't exist in Google Script?

Answer (score 0):

is it a string of words with single quotes and a comma to separate them? if so, you can just do a split on the comma
var s = data
var arr = s.split(",");
and now you will have an array of strings. not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: OK, I tried doing this:

var sNameArray = studentNames.split(",")

  I got the "TypeError: Cannot find function split in object ['user1','user2','user3']

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for getting me pointed in the right direction.

Turns out split was just part of the answer, I had to turn it into a string first.

.toString().split(",");

Answer (score 0):

getValues() returns an object, so you need to interact with it to get the string of values for your array.

Given you are selecting just one cell and so don't need to iterate through the object, try something like this:

```
var studentNamesObj = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REDACTED').getSheetByName('Student List').getRange(3,3).getValues();
var studentNames = studentNamesObj[0][0].split(",");
```

Comment: Just read OPs own answer - toString() is a much neater solution, nice one.  I didn't know about that :-).